# python: 'int' object has no attribute '__iadd__'

Tags: python

I declared a integer variable `x` with value `0`.

```
>>> x = 0
```

When i run this line:

```
>>> x += 3
>>> x
3
```

Everything goes well. But when i run this line:

```
>>> x.__iadd__(3)
```

Python raises an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__iadd__'
```

Why python throws this exception while in [official python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__iadd__) for `operator` module said `+=` operator calls `__iadd__` method?

Comment: Because `x += y` falls back to `x = x + y` if `__iadd__` isn't defined. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__

Answer (score 6):

> in official python documentation for `operator` module said `+=` operator calls `__iadd__` method?

No, it says that `a += b` is equivalent to `a = operator.iadd(a, b)`, not `a.__iadd__(b)`.

`operator.iadd(a, b)` is not equivalent to `a.__iadd__(b)`. `operator.iadd` falls back to `__add__` and `__radd__` if `__iadd__` is not present or returns `NotImplemented`.

Answer (score 4):

It does not say that; what you're linking to in the documentation is the `operator` module:

> `operator.iadd(a, b)`
>   `operator.__iadd__(a, b)`
>
> `a = iadd(a, b)` is equivalent to `a += b`.

The `operator` module contains function equivalents for operators and similar things, it doesn't define standard Python operators. It doesn't say anything about `x.__iadd__`.

---

The relevant documentation is rather [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__):

> `object.__iadd__(self, other)`
>
> These methods are called to implement the augmented arithmetic assignments (`+=`, ...). These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying *self*) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be, *self*). **If a specific method is not defined, the augmented assignment falls back to the normal methods.** ...

So, an object *can* define `__iadd__` to override the behaviour of a `+=` operation, but if such a method is not defined, it falls back to the default `a = a + b` behaviour.